# Google Maps API for Android, faster/efficient way to to retrieve location based info?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Although I know how to programatically retrieve a user's location in Android, as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }

                if(isGPSEnabled) {
                    if(location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if(locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if(location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if(locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And I even know how to programatically utilize the Google search page for location based info (for instance *leisure centers nearby*, *Films showing nearby*, *Restaurants nearby*, *Cafes nearby*) - via utilizing page url etc.

And then download the page as a string. as below:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/leisure+centers+nearby/

```
public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

But what I would like to do

Is to accomplish this a lot faster by using the Google Maps Api to retrieve a list of for instance *leisure centers nearby*, *Films showing nearby*, *Restaurants nearby* or even *Cafes nearby*.

Rather than using the long-winded approach described above.

Answer (score 0):

I made an Abstract class a while a go for a project that needed to use location updates.

Basically, you just need to extend `ActivityLocation` and override `onLocationUpdate(Location location)` and you get the location info you need. Make requests after that :)

```
/**
 * Created by rakeeb on 11/24/14.
 */
public abstract class ActivityLocation extends ActivitySession implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private static final int GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST = 9000;

    public Location location;
    public GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private static final long LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;
    public LocationRequest locationRequest;

    int playResult;

    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public ProjectPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        preferences = new ProjectPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        if (!preferences.isPlayServicesAvailable()) {
            playResult = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            isPlayServiceAvailable(playResult);
        } else {
            startApiClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopLocationRequest();
        stopApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    public void isPlayServiceAvailable(int playResult) {
        switch (playResult) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                preferences.setPlayServicesAvailable(true);
                startApiClient();
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID:
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(playResult, this,
                        GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void startApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(
                LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }


    public void stopApiClient() {
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void startLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }


    public void stopLocationRequest() {
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, LOCATION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(
                "Play services error").setMessage(
                LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
                        this, errorCode));
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        // close application on dialog dismissed ??
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        onLocationUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        switch (cause) {
            case GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST:
            case GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                // connection lost, disable UI
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        startLocationRequest();
    }

    public abstract void onLocationUpdate();
}
```

And about the `onStart()`, rather than doing a play services check all the time, I'm quering my preference to see if play services is available or not.

To get nearby information you'll need to request the [`Place Search API`](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search), please read the documentation properly.

The basic request url has the following structure:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/output?parameters

You'll have to specify [`parameters`](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#RadarSearchRequests) as per your need.

when using the parameter `location` you'll have to specify the lat/lng like this `location=40.717859,-73.9577937`

Your request url will look like this:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=40.717859,-73.9577937&radius=1600&key=API_KEY

**Example:**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ActivityLocation {

    ...

    boolean makeRequest = true;

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdate(Location location) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        // boolean flag to prevent multiple requests
        if(makeRequest) {
            startRequest(lat, lng);
            makeRequest = false;
        }
    }

    public void startRequest(String lat, String lng) {
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?radius=500&sensor=false&key=googleAPIKey&location=" + lat + "," + lng;
        JSONObject object = getResponse(url);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very thankful for your response. But can't see how to use above, to attain location based information like: *Leisure centers nearby*, *Films showing nearby*, *Restaurants nearby*, *Cafes nearby*. An example would be very helpful :-) Thanks

Comment: hmmm give me a moment then.